# REGEX for selecting multiple value in string

Tags: mysql, regex

I need an sql select statement to retrieve 04:30 and test.zip from this string:

```
{"TIME":"04:30","DATE":"11\/25\/2013","FILENAME":["test.zip"]}
```

Comment: why dont you make column for time and one for date and one for filename ?? you save space and break your mind to decode it ?

Comment: Looks like you're trying to use MySQL as a NoSQL/document database. It's not very good at that.

Comment: Let us know what you tried...

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just decode it and use PHP? (assuming you can't change the way it's stored in the db)

```
<?php
$str = '{"TIME":"04:30","DATE":"11/25/2013","FILENAME":["test.zip"]}';
$o = json_decode($str);
$time = $o->TIME;
$file = $o->FILENAME[0];
var_dump($time); //"04:30"
var_dump($file); //"test.zip"
```

Regex replaces etc in MySQL require a UDF (user-defined function) [mysql-udf-regexp](https://github.com/hholzgra/mysql-udf-regexp)

If none of the above are viable solutions (change DB structure, do it with PHP, use a MySQL UDF), you'll need to get creative. It would require a known, static format of that string, but you could replace some parts and substring others. For example:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(REPLACE(`column_name`,'{"TIME":"',''),1,5) AS `time` FROM `table_name`
```

File is more complex, this example assuming only one filename in the array

```
SELECT REPLACE(SUBSTRING(`column_name`,LOCATE('"FILENAME":["',`column_name`)+13),'"]}','') AS `file` FROM `table_name`
```

Those two field selections get `04:30` and `test.zip` respectively (you can of course use those functions in the same statement, rather than separately like I have, by comma separating them)

Answer (score 0):

use this `\[(.*?)\]`

it return value between `[` and `]`

and for 04:30 use `TIME":(.*?),`

it return value after `"TIME":`